# Bash: find directory group owner

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I am sure this is easy but i cant find it.

I am writing a bash script where i want to add a known user to a group.
The group name is determined by the directory, which is sent through as a variable to that bash script.

so:

```
DIR="whatever"
GROUP=DIR groupname 
usermod -a -G $GROUP userx
```

Comment: I am not sure what a 'directory group owner' would be. A directory has an owner and a group. Those are not intertwined.  Members of that group are listed in /etc/groups.

Comment: you're absolutely right, i just couldn't think of the right way to phrase it, "directory group" doesnt sound right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`stat -c %g <file>` (Linux)

`stat -f %g <file>` (BSD)

Will return the group ID for the given `<file>`

EDIT:

`stat -c %G <file>` (Linux)

`stat -f %Sg <file>` (BSD)

Will return the group name.

Comment: excellent, thanks.. i knew (and desperately hoped) it would be easy!

Comment: And `stat -c %U nfsmnt` for the "user name of owner" as per the man page.

Answer (score 0):

This is admittedly way more convoluted, but has the benefit of being more cross-platform friendly:

User:

`\ls -l "$(dirname $TARGET_FILE)" | grep -v '^l' | grep " $(basename $TARGET_FILE)\$" | awk '{ print $3 }'`

Group:

`\ls -l "$(dirname $TARGET_FILE)" | grep -v '^l' | grep " $(basename $TARGET_FILE)\$" | awk '{ print $4 }'`

Breaking it down:

- Use `\ls`. The backslash avoids any shell aliases that might set default options like `-F`.
- Build a `-l`ong format listing of the parent dir for `$TARGET_FILE`.
- `grep -v '^l'` removes any symlinks that might point to `$TARGET_FILE` from the listing and passes on the rest.
- Next narrow down the results to the single line from ls that ends in the basename of `$TARGET_FILE`. The leading `' '` (space) and trailing `\$` are important to match the entire basename. (Otherwise `old_file`, `file_new` and `file` might all come up.)
- Finally, pass the single ls -l row for the target file to awk, and grab the 3rd (or 4th) space-separated item as the user (or group) name.

Note that this implementation has trouble with relative directories. (Don't try to run it where `TARGET_FILE=../` for example.) I'm sure it could be hardened some more using `realpath`, but that's not available on OS X, so we're back to platform-specific tools if we use that.

Comment: I've recently discovered a shortcoming of this approach. If you run this with a path to `$TARGET_FILE` where its parent directory is a symlink, you might not get any output. This is because the symlink name might not match the target folder name. So take the example where `~/public_html` is a symlink to `/var/www/sites/username/html/`. Since "public_html" doesn't match "html", no output will be returned. I will update my answer if I find a solution for this.